# Deactivate some color categories by default

Tags: python, plotly

Hello I am creating an offline html dashboard which consists of multiple plots.
Per default all group option are set to active after the plot is created. I would like to manually set deactivate some of the option. Is there a way to do this?

E.g.
I create a chart with the following code:

```
fig = px.line(test_df, x="date", y="values", color="Group")
fig
```

And the results looks like this (for simplicity reasons I have greatly reduced the amount of data. )
[image]

If I now click on the P the red line disappears. I would like to have this Line deactivated per default.

[image]

The reason why I want this is that in my plot there will be very many groups. While in most cases only a few are relevant I do not want to remove the option to look at the less relevant ones, from time to time.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: Why do you plot the whole dataframe then? You can select the columns you want and discard the others.

Comment: Also, can you share the dataframe and provide a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @alec_djinn they don't want to remove the option to view those columns entirely – just when the app is initialized. imagine if there's 20 columns but you only want to view a few at a time

Comment: @DerekO It is not clear where this decision is made. Is it before plotting or after it?

Comment: plotly will store all of the data needed to render any of the data from the columns and the trace visibility can be toggled by clicking in the legend. if you look at the duplicate question and answers, this decision is made before the plot is rendered – so we already know which traces will be shown on the plot by default